# i need to call one angular2 function name editAppointment from EDIT option

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

This is dynamic carousel code
i need to call one angular2 function name editAppointment from EDIT option given in code, i have tried all the options i could, JQuery can be used

```
   str+=`<div class="item">
             <img src="`+this.eventData[0].events[i].images +`" style="display:none;" >
         <br/>
         <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3" (click)="editAppointment()">EDIT</div>
              <div class="col-sm-4" style="font-size:18px;">APPOINTMENTS</div>
              <div class="col-sm-4 text-right id="delete-appointment">DELETE</div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h5 class="text-center" style="font-weight:bold">TIME</h5>
        <hr style="margin:5px;">
        <p class="text-center">`+mydate+`</p>
        <br/>
        <h5 class="text-center" style="font-weight:bold">DURATION</h5>
        <hr style="margin:5px;">
        <p class="text-center">`+parseInt(""+this.eventData[0].events[i].specificDate.duration/60)+`&nbsp;mins</p>
        <br/>
        <h5 class="text-center" style="font-weight:bold">LOCATION</h5>
        <hr style="margin:5px;">
        <p class="text-center">`+this.eventData[0].events[i].specificDate.location+`</p>
        <br/>
        <h5 class="text-center" style="font-weight:bold">NOTES</h5>
        <hr style="margin:5px;">
        <p class="text-center">`+this.eventData[0].events[i].specificDate.notes+`</p>
        <br/>
        </div>
        `;
        }
```

> I need to call Angular2 function from EDIT Option 
>   function name is editAppointment();

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like OK. This issue can be caused **by css**(default bootstrap or your styles).Your EDIT div probably either inherits a different position value.

*What you can do about this?*

- Changing div position to relative.it enables z-index and moves your
  EDIT div on top of other divs.